# How is the backward propagation is done in pytroch? When to use torch.no_grad, also when and where is the gradinte calcuated?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, backpropagation

I have this training loop in pytorch. the `loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` and `optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)`

```
    for X, y in train_dataloader:

        X = X.to(device)

        y = y.to(device)

        optim.zero_grad()

        pred = net(X)

        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        train_loss += loss.item() * X.size(0)

        pred = torch.argmax(pred, dim= -1)

        train_correct += (pred == y).float().sum()

        with torch.no_grad():

            loss.backward()

            optim.step()
```

now it works fine and the model runs well and gets an accuarcy of 0.99.

My question is why does `loss.backward()` work if `with torch.no_grad` should make it not possible to calculate the gradient of the trainable weights. And if `with torch.no_grad()` was not there would it be the exact same training loop and possibly output the same output. I understand that `optim.step()` doesn't change the gradient right? But subtracts the gradient from the weights. So why use `with torch.no_grad`.